# Spell at days to circumference globe (6)

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

I'm not very happy with this cryptic clue that appeared on [Lovatt's Cryptic Crossword](https://lovattspuzzles.com/online-puzzles-competitions/daily-cryptic-crossword/) for 22 May 2023:

> Spell at days to circumference globe (6)

The answer was:

> EIGHTY - seems to be a reference to "Around the World in Eighty Days" by Jules Verne.

But I don't like it because the clue doesn't seem to be grammatical to me and there doesn't seem to be a good surface interpretation.

I know that...

> spell can refer to a period of time, as in "eighty days", but the form "spell at days" doesn't seem to be a real thing - shouldn't it be "spell of days" or "spell in days"?

Also, ...

> circumference seems to be used as a verb but that isn't supported by any of the dictionaries I checked. Did they mean circumnavigate?

Am I right to quibble about this clue or have I missed something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the right way to decode this clue is to consider

> "Spell at" as "spell AT", which, when spelled out loud, sounds like EIGHTY. The other half is the definition, a reference to Verne's novel as you rightfully said.

Comment: But in the other half, it should still be "circumnavigate" not "circumference", right?

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to the existing answer:

> The word "circumference" *can* be used as a verb according to the OED:

> > circumference v.
> >  rare.
> >  *transitive*. To form the circumference of, to encompass

> > 1887   Talmage in Voice 15 Dec. 7
> >  The earth is diametered and circumferenced with discord.